# Group a single column in multible join query

Tags: sql

I have wrote a sql query which has join many tables and I only want to group a single column of table. And here is my slq query.

```
select us.Username, ro.Role, ca.CartName, ca.Date from Users us
left join Roles ro on ro.RoleID = us.RoleID
left join Carts ca on ca.UserId = us.ID
group by ca.Date;
```

And here is the tables' destruction:

//Table Users

```
ID           Username           RoleID
1            Tri                1
2            Lan                1
3            Nhu                1
4            Lac                1
5            Linhchi            2
```

//Table Roles

```
RoleID       Role               Description
1            Admin              Someone in administrator board
2            User               Someone who has an account
3            Guess              Someone who just view the website
```

//Table Carts

```
CartId       CartName           CartDescription              UserId           Date
1            Computer           Computer CMS                 1                2/11/2013 12:00:00 AM
2            Desk               Writing Desk                 2                2/11/2013 12:00:00 AM
3            Print Paper        Company's print paper        3                3/11/2013 12:00:00 AM
4            Headphone          Small headphone              3                2/11/2013 12:00:00 AM
5            MP3Player          MP3Player Portable           4                4/11/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

//DesireTable after run the query

```
Username         Role          CartName              Date
Tri              Admin         Computer              2/11/2013 12:00:00 AM
Lan              Admin         Desk                  2/11/2013 12:00:00 AM
Lan              Admin         Headphone             2/11/2013 12:00:00 AM
Nhu              Admin         Print Paper           3/11/2013 12:00:00 AM
Lac              Admin         MP3Player             4/11/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

So the result must group by column "Date" from "Carts" table. But the query generated an error message *"Column 'Carts.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."* I got stuck in current context, I need your help to solve this issue.

Comment: can you post sample records with desired result?

Comment: I will, wait a minute.

Comment: You can't select a whole lot of non-aggregated columns and just group by one of them, it doesn't make sense. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have edit the question with more description on my issue. I need some help on my stuck.

Comment: I just want to group by only one column Date but do not want to group other columns from multiple join tables. So if I insert all columns from multiple join tables into group by statement, then how can I control the only one column which I want to group?

Comment: i think, If you simply put "Order by ca.Date", you can get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my issue, I only want to group one single column "Date" but if I insert only one column Date in group by statement, it will generate an error. Thus, I will insert all column from joined tables into group by clause.

```
select us.Username, ro.Role, ca.CartName, ca.Date from Users us
left join Roles ro on ro.RoleID = us.RoleID
left join Carts ca on ca.UserId = us.ID
group by ca.Date, us.Username, ro.Role, ca.CartName;
```

The trick to group only one column which I want to group is put that column in the first place of group by clause, so that it will group that column first and then the other later. By doing this way I can control the group information as I want.